# How to change color of first letter in razor view?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on some blog website in asp.net. Using razor layout pages to present all content data from database. First paragraph in content part is reserved for some sub Title and got style rules for first letter like font-size, color etc.

```css
#post-content .blog-post p:first-child {
  font-size: 1.85em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

#post-content .blog-post p:first-child:first-letter {
  color: #43464b;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2.85em;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 6px 8px -5px 0;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<section id="post-content" class="b-container">

  <div class="blog-post">
    @*first paragraph reserved for title*@
    <p>
      @Model.PostSubhead1

    </p>
    @*first paragraph end*@
    <p>
      @Model.PostText1
    </p>
    <figure>
      <img src="@Url.Content(Model.PostBigImage1)" class="big-image" />
      <em class="img-text">
                   @Model.PostBigImageText1
                </em>
    </figure>

  </div>
</section>
```

How can i set color of `first-letter` from database ? Because every post got different color for first letter in title.

Comment: Are you going to accept an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't implement pseudo effects using inline CSS.

A (poor) work-around for this problem is to have your js add style blocks when they are needed. For example:

```js
var colors = ["#6e2d5b", "#b2a9e9", "#489b34", "#5765a9"];
var i = 0;
function addArticle() {
  i++;
  //get the color and put it in a var named color
  var color = colors[i%4];
  //generate a custom classname and put it in a var named customClass
  var customClass = "_" + color.substr(1);
  var articles = document.getElementById("articles");
  var article = document.createElement("div");
  article.className = customClass;
  article.innerHTML = "content goes here";
  articles.appendChild(article);
  var css = "." + customClass + "::first-letter{color: " + color + ";} ";
  document.getElementById("style").appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
```

```html
<style id="style">

</style>
<div id="articles">
</div>
<button onclick="addArticle();">add an aricle</button>
```

Comment: can i achieve this using `javascript` if yes can anyone show me how ?

Comment: @AleksandarJeftic I updated my answer with a working snippet